# Creating Python code to pin and rotate fixed length segment using shapely

Tags: line, shapely, linestring

I am very new to Python GIS.

I am creating code in Python using shapely geometry library. One of the goals is to create a fixed length segment, pin one end of it to a known coordinate and rotate the segment, keeping, of course, the length constant. I have created the line with

```
line = LineString([Point(px0, py0), Point(px1, py1)])
```

where px0 and py0 is where I want the segment to be anchored. I can now look for px1, and px2 using trigonometry. However, it would be very nice if I could simply describe this segment by its length and angle. I wonder if there is a library already built that does the trick. I have searched the shapely documentation without success.

Comment: This would not be a common helper function, but writing your own trigonometry expression should be simple enough (SOH-CAH-TOA)

Answer (score 1):

Shapely contains a method for line rotation: *affinity.rotate*. Have a look to the [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). Create a LineString centered at 0,0 along the x axis and rotate it and translate it (if needed) after. For example

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely import affinity
line = LineString([(0, 0), (4, 0)])
rotated = affinity.rotate(line, 90, origin=(0,0))
```